# How do I print topological sort and also detect cycles?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using a method DFS which marks the visited node as visited and puts the string into the result stack.

This is a DAG which mean two Nodes can point to the same node as long as its not pointing back and creating a cycle. I created a Test case to create a cycle.

I am pointing `a -> b -> c -> d -> e` then I point `z -> d` and `z -> d` and then `z -> a`

[image]

I am pretty sure the culprit is the DFS algo called `dfs`. I have tried changing it but I am having a hard time figuring out the logic.

I node has a boolean called visited which I set to true and the I set to false after I have traversed its children. If I end up running into a true node then I print cyclic and end the program.

I am looking for guidance on a better way to implement this exact problem. Is there logical error in my dfs? I think thats where the problem lies.

```
package ChaseInterview;

import java.util.*;

public class ChaseInterview {

    public static class Node<T> {
        T val;
        HashSet<Node<T>> adj = new HashSet<>();
        boolean visited = false;

        public Node(T val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public Node() {
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return val.toString() + adj.toString();

        }
    }

    public static class DAG<T> {
        Node<T> root = new Node<T>();
        HashMap<T, Node<T>> map = new HashMap<>();

        public void DAG() {
        }


        public void add(T val) {
            if (map.containsKey(val)) return;
            Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(val);
            map.put(val, newNode);
            root.adj.add(newNode);
        }

        public void add(T val1, T val2) {
            Node<T> node1 = map.containsKey(val1) ? map.get(val1) : new Node<T>(val1);
            Node<T> node2 = map.containsKey(val2) ? map.get(val2) : new Node<T>(val2);
            if (!map.containsKey(val1)) root.adj.add(node1);
            if (root.adj.contains(node2)) root.adj.remove(node2);

            node1.adj.add(node2);
            map.put(val1, node1);
            map.put(val2, node2);
        }

        public String print() {
            Stack<T> stack = new Stack<>();
            dfs(stack, root);
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                res.append(stack.pop());
            }


            return res.reverse().toString();


        }

        public void dfs(Stack<T> stack, Node<T> root) {
            if (root.visited) {
                System.out.println("Cyclic");
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            root.visited = true;

            // populate stack
            if (!(root.val == null) && !stack.contains(root.val)) stack.push(root.val);

            // traverse nodes
            if (!root.adj.isEmpty()) {
                for (Node<T> node : root.adj) {
                    dfs(stack, node);
                }
            }

            root.visited = false;

        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HelloWord");

        DAG<Character> dag = new DAG<Character>();
        dag.add('a', 'b');
        dag.add('b', 'c');
        dag.add('z');
        dag.add('c', 'd');
        dag.add('d', 'e');
        dag.add('d', 'z');
        dag.add('z', 'd');
        dag.add('z', 'a');
        //dag.add('b','a');

        System.out.println(dag.map.size());
        System.out.println(dag.print());
        System.out.println(dag.map.size());


    }
}
```

output:

```
6

6
```

Comment: @GhostCat sorry about "better way" fixed that. other than that I pasted the entire code. The inputs as well as the output and also a picture representation of the graph. I dont know what else I can do honestly.

Comment: Well, what is required here is: to debug the algorithm. Point is: when you do not know what your code is doing, then have your code PRINT its intermediate steps. Or learn how to use a debugger. Maybe you are "lucky" and somebody here does that for you here ... but in the end, such work is an essential part of learning programming. So my advice: go for the smallest example that exposes the problem (probably leave out "b", "c", and "e"). Use a piece of paper and a pen and "run" your algorithm using only that. Figure how it should behave.

Comment: Maybe that already exposes your problem to you. If not, you can then run your implementation and have that print key steps. Maybe the outcome deviates from your expectations. Then look WHY that is. That is how you can approach such problems.

Comment: already been doing it. The logic for the DFS is where the culprit lies. idk how to clarify the logic even more. I myself am actually fuzzy on the logic. but The program should print something. and its not. I am still running the problem but I just wanted some fresh eyes on it.

Comment: As said: when you do not understand what your code is doing: add MORE print statements. Worst case, do a print after every statement you have in your dfs method.

Comment: Thought about everything and slept on it over night.. fixed it and posted.. but thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you got through it!

Comment: this implementation of DFS is weird on so many levels. why are you taking the recursive approach but are still using a stack datastructure? just decide on one of the approaches and maybe don't mix them together, makes your life easier: https://www.techiedelight.com/depth-first-search

Answer (score 0):

I re-did the dfs and print methods to this:

new DFS:

- if root visited then cycle exists
- if stack contains root val then branch has been traversed. just return
- mark root to visited
- dfs adjacent nodes
- push root val to stack
- mark root unvisited

New print() // returns topsort I should change the name I know

- make a result stack and string builder
- loop through map.keySet
- if key.val not in stack -> call dfs
- pop stack to string builder
- string

```
        public String print() {
            Stack<T> stack = new Stack<>();
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            for(T val: map.keySet()){
                if (!stack.contains(val)) dfs(stack,map.get(val));
            }
            while(!stack.isEmpty()) res.append(stack.pop());
            return res.toString();
        }

        public void dfs(Stack<T> stack, Node<T> root) {
            if (root.visited) {
                System.out.println("Cycle at :" + root.val.toString());
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            if (stack.contains(root.val)) return;
            root.visited = true;
            for (Node<T> n: root.adj) dfs(stack,n);
            stack.add(root.val);
            root.visited =false;
        }
```